# Prevent the serverless framework from uploading artifact

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Im using [serverless framework](https://www.serverless.com/) to try to implement [AWS Step functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/). I have the Lambda functions running correctly. These are packaged in a `.jar` and I've manually uploaded to AWS s3.

I then have point to this `.jar` path on s3 in my `serverless.yaml` file:

```
service: serverless-card-issue

package:
  artifact: https://s3.amazonaws.com/integration-builds/serverless/HelloWorldFunction-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I run:

```
sls deploy --stage integration-beta
```

This then takes 10-15 minutes to complete - far too long. In the logs I see:

```
Serverless: Running "serverless" installed locally (in service node_modules)
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Uploading CloudFormation file to S3...
Serverless: Uploading artifacts...
Serverless: Uploading service HelloWorldFunction-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar file to S3 (72.14 MB)...
```

Firstly, I have no idea how it's locating the `HelloWorldFunction-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` file locally - it's in a completely different directory.

Secondly, I do NOT want serverless to upload any `.jar` - it's already on s3.

How can I do this?

Comment: I have already written 2 lambdas functions and uploaded to s3 in a jar. Now using serverless to create a step function workflow, and trigger the lambda functions within the jar...

Comment: It is working perfect locally, so now I want to try on AWS

Answer (score -1):

The `deploy` target automatically executes the `package` target in the background, i.e. it creates the JAR file automatically, and doesn't use any locally existing JAR. Additionally, the `deploy` target also automatically deploys the artifact to S3, so if you want to skip that part, add the parameter `--noDeploy` to your command. See also https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/deploy/

Comment: Thanks, trying this but getting new error, probably unrelated